# Fluxbox: Wallpaper settings in fluxbox will always reset

Tags: debian, fluxbox

I just installed a fresh new debian and after that I installed fluxbox. I logged in with my normal user and start fluxbox with startx.

I've now got a simple wallpaper with the debian-logo. When using `fbsetroot -solid grey10` the background changed as aspected. But whene restarting fluxbox the default wallpaper returns.

I've tried a couple of things:

1. `background: none` in *~/.fluxbox/overlay*
2. `background: unset` in *~/.fluxbox/overlay*
3. `session.screen0.rootCommand:    fbsetbg -l` in *~/.fluxbox/init*
4. `/usr/bin/fbsetbg -l &` in *.fluxbox/startup*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Ive double checked all single setting places descriped in the question above and did two things now:

1. in *init* I set the rootCommand to *fbsetroot -solid grey15*
2. int *startup* I commend out the line with *fbsetbg -l*

Comment: Congratulations! If this solved your problem, consider accepting your own answer, so that in future other people may benefit from it.

Comment: @MatthewRock: Thanks :) Yeah I will do so once the waiting time of 2 days are passed

Comment: almost. rootCommand is deprecated, one sets the wallpaper via the theme/style. read http://fluxbox.org/help/man-fluxbox-style.php#_background more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the command to your [.xinitrc file](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc):

Comment: doesn't work. Content: `fbsetroot -solid grey15 _<newline>_ exec startfluxbox`

Answer (score 0):

`fbsetbg` != `fbsetroot`. See [here](http://fluxbox.sourceforge.net/docbook/en/html/chap-bg.html):

> fbsetroot is about the equivalent of xsetroot, which can set
>   backgrounds as long as they're simple, like a solid color. fbsetroot
>   can also set gradients.
>
> fbsetbg is a wrapper that tries to find a suitable background-setting
>   app and then tries to set the wallpaper using that app. You don't have
>   to configure fbsetbg. It just uses the first app it can find.

`fbsetbg` with `-l` will load a wallpaper saved in `~/.fluxbox/lastwallpaper` which contains a saved wallpaper for different `DISPLAYS`, for example:

```
$full $full|/usr/share/fluxbox/debian-blueish-wallpaper.png|style|:0
$full $full|/home/ja/wallpaper/635429481129181928.jpg||:0.0
$full|$full/home/ja/wallpaper/635429481129181928.jpg||:1.0
```

Comment: so what would you sugges to do in my case (note the above 4 steps)?